# Can I display left navigation bar in LTI Tool launch screen in Blackboard Learn?

Tags: lti, blackboard

I have developed and configured an LTI Tool in Blackboard Learn and it is running fine. When I click on the link in the LTI Tool, it gets launched in an iframe without left navigation bar.

I have checked a few existing default Tools such as Wikis and Announcements which also contains left navigation bar. I want to display my LTI Tool with the left navigation bar in a course shell like as Wikis and Announcements tool. I didn't find any configurations during LTI Tool setup for a course. Is it possible to display left navigation bar for an LTI Tool in Blackboard Learn? Could you please help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The end user decides in Blackboard if your LTI tool launches in a new window or the same window.  If it is started in the same window you'll see the tabs and breadcrumbs, but depending on Blackboard version, you may not be able to see the left menu.

Tools started in Ultra courses have the purple close button in the upper left which let you come back to the course navigation ...

To run the tool with left navigation you may need to build a Building Block instead.